# Node js- not able to define chunk constant

Tags: javascript, node.js

The function activated by the listener on http.incomingMessage is not working properly, it is supposed to define the constant chunk white the submited input but for some reason it remain UNDEFINED.

I dont get any error message but the page wont stop loading after accessing the page.

```
      const http = require('http');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    const method = req.method;
    if (url === '/') {
      res.write('<html>');
      res.write('<head><title>Enter Message</title></head>');
      res.write('<body>');
      res.write('<form action="/message" method="POST">');
      res.write('<input type="text">');
      res.write('<input type="submit">');
      res.write('</form>');
      res.write('</body>');
      res.write('</html>');
      return res.end();
    }
    if (url === '/message') {
      const body = [];
      req.on('data', chunk => {
        body.push(chunk);

      });

      return req.on('end', () => {
        const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
        console.log(parsedBody);



        fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', message, err => {
          res.statusCode = 302;
          res.setHeader('Location', '/');
          return res.end();
        });
      });

    }

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title>Enter Message</title></head>');
    res.write('<body>');
    res.write('<p>My page</p>');
    res.write('</body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();
  });

  server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: `res.end;` should be `res.end();`

Comment: Thanks but it still get the same problem.

Comment: Ok, well what exactly is `UNDEFINED` that shouldn't be? It sounds to me like you may not actually have anything being sent chunked - that would explain the empty body, and I'd be at least logging out the `err` Param on `writeFileSync`, that will most likely be failing hence why the request doesn't end

Comment: Thanks it helped a bit, now the page redirect properly at least but the message constant remains undefined.

Comment: what message constant? I don't see a const in your code

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function properly, change your `res.end;` to `res.end();`.
In order to finish sending a request you have to invoke the [res.end()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback) function

Comment: Thanks but even correcting that mistake it does not work